# Is composition of regular epimorphisms always regular?

Tags: category-theory

In a finitely complete and cocomplete category. Does it always hold that the composition of two regular epimorphisms is regular? And if it's not the case, what kind of additional constraints can make it true (say, a pre-abelian category)?

What I already knew is it holds for categories where regular epimorphisms and strong epimorphisms conincide.

Comment: Well, strong epimorphisms are always composable, so the hypothesis that regular epi = strong epi just transfers that property to regular epimorphisms. I do not believe that regular epimorphisms are composable in general.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you think it holds for pre-abelian categories? I tried to prove it in this special case  by mimicking diagram chasing trick, but failed.

Comment: No, it is false even there. See exercise 5(c) [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/CTSheet4-2013.pdf).

Comment: A sufficient condition is that regular epimorphisms are pullback stable epimorphisms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a category with all kernel pairs and coequalisers of kernel pairs, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. regular epimorphisms are stable under composition;
2. regular epimorphisms coincide with strong epimorphisms;
3. for any morphism $f$, if $m_f \circ e_f$ is its factorisation through the coequaliser of its kernel pair, $m_f$ is a monomorphism;
4. regular epimorphisms and monomorphisms form a factorisation system.

This is proved in [Monomorphisms, Epimorphisms, and Pull-backs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700005693) by Kelly (Propositions 2.7 and 3.8).  Note: Kelly takes as definition of regular epimorphism what is called elsewhere [strict epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+epimorphism), but these notions coincide when kernel pairs exist.  (And Kelly doesn’t give the “factorisation system” version.)

Kelly gives an example of a pre-abelian category in which regular monomorphisms do not compose: the category of abelian groups with no elements of order 4 (last paragraph of p. 126).  The dual category is a pre-abelian category in which regular epimorphisms do not compose.

Comment: Note: 3 of the implications are easy. 3 $\to$ 4: we have the factorisation; the orthogonality is the inclusion of regular into strong epimorphisms.  4 $\to$ 2: in a factorisation system, the “epi” morphisms are exactly the morphisms orthogonal to the “mono” morphisms.  2 $\to$ 1: strong epimorphisms compose.  The proof of 1 $\to$ 3 is a bit more involved: you factorise $m_f$ as $m' \circ e'$ through the coequaliser of its own kernel pair, and use the regularity of $e' \circ e_f$ to prove that $e'$ is an isomorphism, so that the kernel pair of $m_f$ is trivial and $m_f$ is a monomorphism.

Answer (score 7):

My standard example of a category where regular epimorphisms are not closed under composition is the category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of small categories.

Let $\mathbb{2}=\{0\to 1\}$ be the category with two objects and one non-identity morphism between them, and let $F:\mathbb{2}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the functor sending this morphism to $1$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the additive monoid of natural numbers, viewed as 1-object category.

Let $G:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be the inclusion of additive monoids, viewed as functor between the associated 1-object categories, and let $H: \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be the quotient map, again viewed as functor between 1-object categories.

Then $F$ and $H\circ G$ are regular epis in $\mathbf{Cat}$, but $H\circ G\circ F$ is not.