# showing regular epimorphisms are not stable under composition in general

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

The following counterexample is given in response to this question [Is composition of regular epimorphisms always regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652019/is-composition-of-regular-epimorphisms-always-regular/3754110):

"Let $\mathbf{2} =\textbf{{0→1}}$ be the category with two objects and one non-identity morphism between them, and let $F:\textbf{2}→\mathbb{N}$ be the functor sending this morphism to 1, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the additive monoid of natural numbers, viewed as 1-object category.

Let $G:\mathbb{N}→\mathbb{Z}$ be the inclusion of additive monoids, viewed as functor between the associated 1-object categories, and let $H:\mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be the quotient map, again viewed as functor between 1-object categories.

Then $F$ and $H\circ G$ are regular epis in Cat, but $H\circ G\circ F$ is not."

I do not understand any of these conclusions. Why are $F$ and $H \circ G$ regular epimorphisms, and why is $H \circ G 
\circ F$ not a regular epimorphism? I thought $F$ might coequalize a pair of constant functors $K, J: \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{2}$ with $K(C) = 0$ and $J(C) = 1$ since both these objects must be sent by $F$ to the only object $*$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Well, you can't have two non-isomorphic coequalizers of the same two functors, right? You're on the right track, just pick out the simplest imaginable possibility for $\mathcal C,$ then figure out what $H\circ G$ is the coequalizer of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the categories involved have universal properties. $\mathbf2$ is the free category with a morphism, $\mathbb N$ is the free category with an endomorphism, and $\mathbb Z/2$ is the free category with an involution.

$\mathbf2\to\mathbb N$ identifies with one another the two objects of $\mathbf2$, i.e. it coequalizes the two functors $\mathbf 1\to\mathbf2$. It is a coequalizer because any other functor coequalizing those two functors has to identify those two objects, and so has to specify an endomorphism, so factors uniquely out of $\mathbb N$. Thus, $\mathbf2\to\mathbb N$ is a coequalizer.

Similarly, $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z/2$ identifies with one another the identity endomorphism and the square of the generating endomorphism of $\mathbb N$, so coequalizes two functors $\mathbf2\to\mathbb N$. Any functor coequalizing those two has to identify the identity with the square of the generating endomorphism, so has to specify an involution, so factors uniquely out of $\mathbb Z/2$. Thus, $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z/2$ is a coequalizer.

To see that the composite $\mathbf2\to\mathbb Z/2$ is not a coequalizer, we can use the basic fact about regular epimorphisms that a regular epimorphism $f$ is the coequalizer of its kernel pair $p_i$ for $i=1,2$, if the latter exists. This is because by definition of the kernel pair, $fg_1=fg_2$ implies there exists unique $g$ such that $g_i=p_ig$, whence $h$ such that $hp_i$ are the same is an $h$ such that $hp_ig=hg_i$ are the same. In particular, if $f$ is the coequalizer of $g_i$, then $h$ factors uniquely through $f$.

The kernel pair of $\mathbf2\to\mathbb Z/2$ is the subcategory of $\mathbf2\times\mathbf2$ (of a commutative square) consisting of the four identity morphisms and the diagonal morphism, equipped with the two functors to $\mathbf2$ collapsing the square horizontally or vertically. For a functor to coequalize both of these, it would have to map the four objects to a single objects, i.e. giving an endomorphism. Since $\mathbb N$ is the free category with an endomorphism, we see that the coequalizer of the kernel pair of $\mathbf2\to\mathbb Z/2$ is $\mathbf2\to\mathbb N$, not $\mathbf2\to\mathbb Z/2$.

In fact, what's happening is that the kernel pairs of $\mathbf 2\to\mathbb N$ and $\mathbf 2\to\mathbb Z/2$ are the same.

Comment: I must be missing something. I follow until we view the subcategory (call it $\mathcal{C}$) of $\mathbf{2} \times \mathbf{2}$ as the kernel pair of $K: \mathbf{2} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$. It seems like there are distinct functors out of the trivial category $A, B: \mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{2}$ such that $K \circ A = K \circ B$ but there is not a functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ making both of the relevant triangles commute.

Comment: The morphisms in a category $C$ are in bijection with functors $\mathbf 2\to C$, whence $C$ being the kernel pair of $\mathbf 2\to Z/2$ means that its morphisms are pairs of morphisms of $\mathbf 2$ sent to the same morphism by $\mathbf 2\to Z/2$. So these are pairs of identity morphisms (four possibilities, corresponding to the four objects) and the pair of the non-identity morphism with itself (corresponding to the diagonal morphism). Composition of morphisms is component-wise on the pairs, and the functors take the first or second component of the morphisms.

Comment: Thank you very much for the added information. I think I see now. It doesn't seem hard to show $F: \mathbf{2} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the coequalizer of the kernel pair $(Hor, Vert)$ of $K = H \circ G \circ F: \mathbf{2} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. If  $K$ also coequalizes $(Hor, Vert)$ there must be an isomorphism of categories between $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, which there isn't. Thus $K$ doesn't coequalize its kernel pair and is therefore not a regular epimorphism.

Comment: I guess we are using the fact that the category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of small categories has all finite limits hence all kernel pairs, so that regular epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Cat}$ are also *effective epimorphisms* (meaning they coequalizer their kernel pair.)