# Is composition of extremal epimorphisms always extremal?

Tags: category-theory

In

[showing regular epimorphisms are not stable under composition in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296866/showing-regular-epimorphisms-are-not-stable-under-composition-in-general)

a counterexample to the stability wrt to compositions has been provided for regular epimorphisms. Furthermore, it is well known that compositions of strong epimorphisms is again strong. However, in general, the previous statement fails to hold for extremal epimorphisms. But I never found a counterexample in literature. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest example I can think of is the category with three objects and three non-identity morphisms $A\to B\to C$. The two morphisms $A\to B$ and $B\to C$ are extremal, but their composite isn't.

More generally, in any thin category, i.e. one in which there is at most one morphism between any two objects, every morphism is both a mononomorphism and an epimorphism. Consequently, extremal morphisms in a thin category are that do not factor as the composite of two non-isomorphisms, sometimes called "covering" morphisms. Thus in such categories the composition of two extermal non-isomorphisms is not extremal.